# Is it better to store custom keys in the project property list or in a separate one?

Tags: xcode, ios7

This question is related to the procedure of version/build number auto increment scripts. Since Apple doesn't have a specific "build count" property, I was thinking of placing that in a property list and using that within the app itself for identification. It wouldn't be part of the formal version string.

Also the way Apple expects the version strings to be formatted doesn't allow simple incrementing ("1.0" + 1 == err).

Comment: Do you want to actually access the version/build number - but you don't know how?

Comment: Good question, but no. I know how to access properties in a plist, I guess I just don't know the best way to deal with adding custom properties.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I always put in a separate .plist file. For me it looks easier and clean to deal with. I hope that helps.

Comment: Are there any formal recommendations? I couldn't find any myself, but sometimes it's just a matter of knowing what to look for.

Comment: No. I couldn't find on Apple's documentation either. It's just from my personal experience.